# How to detect whether photo/video was taken from camera or imported from camera roll in iphone safari

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

In my website I have a `file input` tag to upload photo/video.
When the website is opened in mobile safari, and when we click on the file input, an Action sheet opens up with 3 options `take photo or Video`, `choose Existing` and `cancel`. 
Is there anyway to determine in js that the file was taken from camera(`take photo or video`), or imported(`choose existing`) from camera roll ?

Comment: Could you use a library like [this](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) to check the metadata? If it was taken in the last few seconds, you could assume it was taken by the phone. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I've a php solution implemented from this, I'm not sure that that's going to help you, but here is the code:

```
<?php

$camera = cameraUsed("C:\Users\Ale\Pictures\sep7imodia.jpg");
echo "Camera Used: " . $camera['make'] . " " . $camera['model'] . "<br />";
echo "Exposure Time: " . $camera['exposure'] . "<br />";
echo "Aperture: " . $camera['aperture'] . "<br />";
echo "ISO: " . $camera['iso'] . "<br />";
echo "Date Taken: " . $camera['date'];

// This function is used to determine the camera details for a specific image. It returns an array with the parameters.

function cameraUsed($imagePath) {

// Check if the variable is set and if the file itself exists before continuing
if ((isset($imagePath)) and (file_exists($imagePath))) {

  // There are 2 arrays which contains the information we are after, so it's easier to state them both
  $exif_ifd0 = read_exif_data($imagePath ,'IFD0' ,0);      
  $exif_exif = read_exif_data($imagePath ,'EXIF' ,0);

  //error control
  $notFound = "Unavailable";

  // Make
  if (@array_key_exists('Make', $exif_ifd0)) {
    $camMake = $exif_ifd0['Make'];
  } else { $camMake = $notFound; }

  // Model
  if (@array_key_exists('Model', $exif_ifd0)) {
    $camModel = $exif_ifd0['Model'];
  } else { $camModel = $notFound; }

  // Exposure
  if (@array_key_exists('ExposureTime', $exif_ifd0)) {
    $camExposure = $exif_ifd0['ExposureTime'];
  } else { $camExposure = $notFound; }

  // Aperture
  if (@array_key_exists('ApertureFNumber', $exif_ifd0['COMPUTED'])) {
    $camAperture = $exif_ifd0['COMPUTED']['ApertureFNumber'];
  } else { $camAperture = $notFound; }

  // Date
  if (@array_key_exists('DateTime', $exif_ifd0)) {
    $camDate = $exif_ifd0['DateTime'];
  } else { $camDate = $notFound; }

  // ISO
  if (@array_key_exists('ISOSpeedRatings',$exif_exif)) {
    $camIso = $exif_exif['ISOSpeedRatings'];
  } else { $camIso = $notFound; }

  $return = array();
  $return['make'] = $camMake;
  $return['model'] = $camModel;
  $return['exposure'] = $camExposure;
  $return['aperture'] = $camAperture;
  $return['date'] = $camDate;
  $return['iso'] = $camIso;
  return $return;

} else {
  return false;
}
}

?>
```

You can take the $camera['date'] value to compare with the actual datetime, and if there are a few seconds difference, you can assume it was taken by the phone just now.