# How to detect if a photo is uploaded from device gallery or taken from camera in Apple iPhone using JavaScript or C#

Tags: javascript, c#, ios, exif

I am developing a small web application for mobile and I am using canvas to draw the images on screen before uploading it to the server.

**Before the upload, I want to know if the photo was taken from the camera roll or taken by the device camera.**

**It will also be good for me to know the photo's original date.**

I know how to do it in Android, but in iOS, this data is unavailable in the EXIF data, until the image is uploaded to the device.

I have found this question: [how to detect where the image is coming from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774903/how-to-detect-whether-photo-video-was-taken-from-camera-or-imported-from-camera), but it has no answers.

I am using [Exif.js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) to extract the metadata in the client side.

Any ideas?

adding the code for extracting EXIF data

```
 $scope.handleFileInput = function (file, invalidFiles) {
        //var file = $scope.photoInput.files[0];
        if (file) {
            if (/^image\//i.test(file.type)) {
                $scope.readFile(file);
            } else {
                alert('Not a valid image!');
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.readFile = function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function (d) {
            var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(d.target.result);
            photoService.validatePhoto(exif.DateTimeOriginal);

            //alert('exif.DateTime = ' + exif.DateTime);
            //alert('exif.DateTimeOriginal = ' + exif.DateTimeOriginal);
            //alert('exif.DateTimeDigitized = ' + exif.DateTimeDigitized);

            $scope.processFile(file, exif.Orientation);
        }

        reader.onerror = function () {
            alert('There was an error reading the file!');
        }

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    };
```

Comment: you could add the code you have tried.

Comment: If you're using C#, you might try my library https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet